# Why is my answer on this question deleted?

Tags: support, closed-questions, deleted-questions

[How does this guy eat?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/88719/how-does-this-guy-eat)

[image]

Napoleon, also closed one of my questions for being "lack of details"! but it was deleted because it was duplicated. Is it a good reason to close a question because of being duplicated? there are many duplicated questions here. why are they still active then?!

and this answer. I don't see any bad things about it. I think some users have personal hostility toward me.

Comment: Would you also be able to link to the question that was closed as duplicate and then deleted?

Comment: no. unfortunately, I can't. I have deleted it for being down-voted 3 times (down-votes were because of my question's duplicity). but I hope it won't happen again (I mean getting closed because of duplicity). Paulie_D and Napoleon... oh, forget it.

Comment: "there are many duplicated questions here. why are they still active then?!" Could you clarify what you mean by "active"? Do you mean there are duplicates that haven't been closed, or there are duplicates that have been closed but not deleted? Bearing in mind that you deleted the duplicate yourself.

Comment: @F1Krazy Yes. I deleted it for down-votes I received. but before it, it was closed. really is it okay to close duplicate questions? And, I mean duplicate questions that haven't been closed. a duplicate question should just get a duplicity banner. it is unfair to close them.

Comment: Just so you're aware, deleting your own questions can contribute towards an automated question ban. Having downvoted questions also contributes, but less so (I believe), and if you *do* trip the ban, the only way out is to go back and edit those downvoted questions to improve them. If you've deleted them all, that becomes a lot harder, as first you have to track them down, then you have to wait for them to get undeleted once you've edited them.

Comment: There is no way to give a duplicate question a duplicate banner and not close it. Closing it as a duplicate is what *gives* the question its duplicate banner. These two things are inseperable. Also, none of your questions were deleted for being duplicates, neither were any closed for "lack of details". Two of your questions were closed as duplicates (the normal procedure as the answers explain) and all question deletions were performed by you. If you are not completely aware of the facts about your deleted posts, feel free to ask the moderators for links to them before making up said facts.

Answer (score 9):

I'm seeing three separate but closely-related issues here: you think your answer was deleted unfairly, you think your question was closed unfairly, and you believe that the moderator responsible for both actions has a personal vendetta against you. I'm going to try and address all three.

Let's start with your deleted answer. I can separate it into two halves:

> They are removable.

Okay, fair enough, that's an attempt to answer the question. But Paulie_D's answer from two years ago already mentioned that, in big bold letters, *and* provided a video demonstration. Answers should provide something new, especially if they're coming so late after the question was posted, and simply repeating something that's already in an existing answer doesn't do that.

> but I'm wondering how big the lip pierced hole is without the plate! What if it is big enough to let the food or drink come out from the mouth and end up on the table?!

This is *not* an attempt to answer the question. It's a pair of follow-up questions. That's not what answers are for. FWIW, Paulie_D's answer also appears to address both of those questions: the first is answered by the video I mentioned earlier, and the second is addressed in the paragraph after it:

> Naturally, the stretched lip would make eating (and drinking) somewhat messy (one would imagine)...

So the first half of your answer is "very low quality", as it doesn't provide any new information, and the second half is "not an answer" because it's an attempt at asking further questions instead of answering the one that was asked. Both are valid reasons for deletion, so unfortunately I have to side with Napoleon on this one.

---

Now, onto your closed question:

> Is it a good reason to close a question because of being duplicated?

Yes, it is a good reason. The user who posted the duplicate gets the answer they were looking for, the answer itself doesn't end up getting split between multiple posts, and anyone else who has the same question in the future has one extra signpost to point them in the right direction. Everybody wins! Sure, it sucks having your question closed, but it doesn't count against you in any way.

If you think a question is a duplicate but it hasn't been closed, you can flag it as a duplicate and the moderators will take a look. The reverse is true: if you think your question isn't a duplicate but it was closed as one, you can edit it to explain why the other question doesn't answer your question, and/or raise it on Meta as you've done here.

I will note that deleting questions if they're closed as duplicates is a bad move, because a) deleted questions count towards the automated question ban, and closed questions don't (unless they're downvoted), and b) you're depriving future visitors of that extra signpost I mentioned earlier.

---

As for your "vendetta" accusation... obviously, I can't really disprove that. I don't know what other users here are thinking. In my experience, though, it's **highly unlikely**. If you see the same user moderating multiple posts of yours - whether it's Napoleon, myself, or anyone else - the most likely explanation is that they're very active and just so happened to bump into those posts in the course of their usual activity.

Speaking for Napoleon, he's been the most active mod here for as long as I can remember, and I have personally seen him close off-topic questions within *five minutes* of them being posted. He didn't have any vendetta against those people. He just happened to be there when they posted, realised it was off-topic, and acted accordingly.

I'm sure when he next logs in, he'll see this and explain his actions for himself, but I personally don't believe he (or anyone else who may have moderated your posts here) has done anything wrong. You would have to provide more evidence than you have in order to convince me otherwise.

Comment: While I might feel obliged to answer this question since it is referring to moderator actions performed by me, you already said pretty much everything I'd have said, too and all I can do is agree with your answer.

Comment: Though, deleting downvoted (or to be precise, negatively scored) duplicates is usually okay, since the value assumption generally doesn't tend to hold for these. Duplicates certainly shouldn't be downvoted just for being duplicates, but if it's actually a *bad* duplicate (judging by negative score), there's not much value in having it stick around as a bad signpost either.

Comment: Shame we can't award bounties on Meta, because this is one very grounded and nicely explained answer to what new users unfamiliar with SE sites may wonder about. Well done, F1Krazy!